# Jquery - Multi array and each

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

i have a problem with the each function.

**HTML**

```
<div id="d1" class="line1"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {


tt = new Array();
tt['id_32'] = new Array("32", "gudfgws", "htdfgss", "0", "gudfgdgfs", "0", "halder", "0");  
tt['id_35'] = new Array("35", "TVdfg.xml", "154", "Was läuft jetzt im TV", "0", "simpsons", "0");
tt['id_36'] = new Array("36", "Gddfge", "httdfg0", "155", "Idfgs", "0", "apple", "0");

   $.each(tt, function(key1,key2)
   {             
       $('#d1').append('-> '+key1+' - '+key2+' <br />');                 
  });

});
```

I dont get anything ... no error and no results. Can anybody tell me where the bug is?

Working example
http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/558/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using named indexes with an array which doesn't work, you need `tt` to be an object instead, like this:

```
var tt = {};
```

[Here's the updated/working version](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8EnCD/3/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    tt = {} //Object
    tt.id_32 = new Array("32", "gudfgws", "htdfgss", "0", "gudfgdgfs", "0", "halder", "0");  
    tt.id_35 = new Array("35", "TVdfg.xml", "154", "Was läuft jetzt im TV", "0", "simpsons", "0");
    tt.id_36 = new Array("36", "Gddfge", "httdfg0", "155", "Idfgs", "0", "apple", "0");

    $.each(tt,function(_key,_array){
       $.each(_array,function(value){
           $('#d1').append('-> '+_key+' - '+value+' <br />')
       });
    })
});
```

Give that a go for me.